# how to showing mysql table with filtering them

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with the composition as follows:

```
invoice     status  value
1234          D     1250
1234          C     1250
2345          D     2300
3456          D     2500
4567          D     2000
4567          C     1250
```

I want to display it or report it selectively like this

```
invoice     status  value
2345          D     2300
3456          D     2500
4567          D     750
```

two invoices with the number 1234 is not appear because it is equal and has the status of D and K
two invoices with the number 4567 is still appear in one row with a value of 750 (formed from 2000 - 1250 = 750)

I want to use the SELECT command but have a trouble to make it,
help me please, thank you

Comment: What is your current SQL request ? What are the criterias to select the lines you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
SELECT invoice,'D' as status,
SUM(case WHEN status='D' THEN value ELSE -value END) as sums
FROM t
GROUP BY invoice
HAVING sums>0
```

Comment: i tried your script but having error like this : "  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values FROM coba GROUP BY invoice HAVING values>0 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2"

Comment: @aguspriyo Used a reserved word,fixed now